# Comparing each element of a list to their corresponding index in another

Tags: python, comparison, list-comprehension

I have a list:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I need to compare this to a series of other lists:

```
list2=[[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[5,4,3,2,1,0]]
```

and flag any of these in which every value in list1 is greater than the value of its corresponding index in list2[n] i.e:

```
list1[0]>list2[n][0], list1[1]>list2[n][1], list1[2]>list2[n][2], list1[3]>list2[n][3], list1[4]>list2[n][4], list1[5]>list2[n][5]
```

Here, it should return TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE

list1 and list2[n] are always of the same length, but this length can differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `zip` and list comprehension to get a pair of elements from `list1` and `list2[n]` and then use `all` to check if for all pairs (x,y), x>y

```
>>> list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list2=[[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,3,4,5],[2,2,2,2,2,2],[5,4,3,2,1,0]]
>>> [all(x>y for x,y in zip(list1,lst)) for lst in list2]
[True, True, False, False]
```

If `list1` and `list2[n]` are of unequal sizes, replace `zip` with `itertools.zip_longest`

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> [all(x>y for x,y in zip_longest(list1,lst, fillvalue=0)) for lst in list2]
[True, True, False, False]
```